# Two error messages for the same ClientAbortException. Difference?

Tags: tomcat

I have a website that runs on Tomcat 8.0.36. When reviewing the logs, I am able to see error messages for the same exception class: ClientAbortException.

```
No 1.
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

No 2. 
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

For the first one, here is what I found:

```
This exception can mean that the connection to the client browser was aborted before the response is fully transferred. It is a harmless warning as it can be due to transient network problems or the user aborts/refreshes the page before it loaded. 
A list of other causes are: 
The user closed the browser before the page loaded.
Their Internet connection failed during loading.
They went to another page before the page loaded.
The browser timed the connection out before the page loaded (would have to be a large page).
```

What about the second one? What is the cause and what the user sees in their browser when it happens?

Comment: Second one is caused by network problems, or at least by failure to receive ACKs from the peer.

Comment: EJP, If this is caused by network, what makes it happen? What does the visitor see in his browser? thanks so much for chiming in!!